# Rails - Validate presence of at least one relation of certain type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a `has_many :through` relationship:

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: {
    intern: 0,
    associate: 1,
    partner: 2,
    admin: 3
  }

  has_many   :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :projects, through: :assignments
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :assignees, through: :assignments, source: :user
end
```

In other words, users can have many projects; projects can have many users ('assignees' in this case).

These assignments can be qualified by their nature: each assignee is either a project owner, or not (that would be the `is_owner` boolean).

```rb
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean "is_owner"
  t.integer "project_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_project_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id"
end
```

How can I enforce that there's always 1) at lease one owner and 2) never more than one owner?

I have tried numerous variants, but my money would be on a validation rule on the project model. Any suggestions as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just add a direct relationship between `Project` and owner ( `User`)? e.g. `belongs_to :owner, class_name: User`. This would be the easiest and cleanest way to perform this requirement

Comment: I've thought about this, but then you might end up with two redundant relationships. In other words, you might end up with an 'owner' and an 'assignee' who are the same person.

Comment: This could be more easily validated in `Assignment` e.g. `validate :not_owner; def not_owner; errors.add(:user_id, 'cannot assign project to Owner') if Project.where(owner_id: user_id, id: project_id).exists?; end`. You could equally validate the same or take action on update of the `Project` owner

Comment: Alright, I'm giving it a shot. On the `User` model, I should then answer to the relationship with something along the lines of `has_many   :owned_projects, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Project` ?

Comment: `has_many :owned_projects, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: Project, dependent: :destroy` foreign_key is important to tell the model what column to use for the association

Comment: While its relatively to write a custom validation method for this if you really had to its very hard to enforce this rule on the database level. @engineersmnky's proposed solution is superior since you can just make the column non-nullable and use foreign key constraints to avoid orphaned records. It will  also let you eager load the owner very efficiently.